# how many trainings are started in any given month SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, count

I have dataset:

Name: Licences

```
id      licence   type      start
 1         1    training  12/08/2017
 2         2    training  17/08/2017
```

I need to count how many licences is used for each month

I tred this:

```
SELECT COUNT(type)
FROM Licences
GROUP BY MONTH(start)
```

But I get only number of all records for whole year, not each month

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should also use it as a column and not just in the group condition:

```sql
SELECT 
date_trunc('month',start) as "month",COUNT(type) as "license_count"
FROM Licences
GROUP BY date_trunc('month',start)
ORDER BY date_trunc('month',start)
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

`SELECT COUNT([type]) as count_types, MONTH([start]) as type_month FROM Licences GROUP BY MONTH([start])`